# CSS Lists: Centering your list text w.r.t list-style-image

Tags: css

Please find the link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1acfLqwr/)

HTML:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li id="bullet">
      <span>Alerts</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bullet{
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    list-style-image: url('https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/09/29/Alerts_icon.png');
}
```

I am trying to vertically center align my List text. I have used list-style-image to include an icon for my list instead of standard bullets.

**Edit1:** As suggested by Eden I replaced my code and it works almost fine. However, the list text is too lengthy for some and when the text is moving to next row, it is starting from below the image/icon. Is there a way in which I can make my text start from exactly where my text started in the previous line?

**Edit2:** Here is my entire HTML of the page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PLM</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="listSlider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="unslider.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>

$(document).ready(function() {
//alert("called");   
//alert($().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite());

var list = "Announcements";                      
var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>";

var query="<Query></Query>";
$().SPServices({
operation: "GetListItems",
async: false, 
listName: "Announcements",
CAMLViewFields: fieldsToRead,
CAMLQuery: query,                                                                    

completefunc: function(xData, Status)
{
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function () 
    {
        //alert(xData.responseXML);
        var _Title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
        //alert(_Title);
        var _Dream_x0020_Destination = $(this).attr("ows_Dream_x0020_Destination");
        var _PPP =  $(this).attr("ows_PPP");

        $("#Announcement").append("<li id='slide'>"+ _Title +"</li>");
    });
}
});

});

</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="designmypage.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foundation.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        <div id="content">
            <article>
            <h1 id="headalign">Product Lifecycle Management</h1>
            <p class="text">What is PLM?</p>    
            <p class="text">Product Lifecycle Management (PLM) helps manufacturers manage complex, cross-functional processes, coordinating the efforts of distributed teams to consistently and efficiently develop the best possible products.</p></article>
            <div id="water"><img src="Landing page/Watermark.png" /></div>
            <div id="chart"><img src="Landing page/Chart.png" /></div>
        </div>
        <div id="contact">
            <div id="rect">
                <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;Contacts:</p>
            </div>
            <div id="cr">
                <ul class="large-block-grid-8">
                    <li><img src="Landing page/Contacts/CassWade.png"></li>
                    <li><p id="Contact_Name_Align">Cass Wade<br/>Project Manager</p></li>
                    <li><img src="Landing page/Contacts/Meredith.png"></li>
                    <li id="align"><p id="Contact_Name_Align">Meredith<br/>HR Head</p></li>
                    <li><img src="Landing page/Contacts/Simon.png"></li>
                    <li id="align"><p id="Contact_Name_Align">Simon<br/>CEO</p></li>
                    <li><img src="Landing page/Contacts/Roger.png"></li>
                    <li id="align"><p id="Contact_Name_Align">Roger<br/>Director</p></li>
                </ul>
            <hr/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar">
        <div id="AT">
            <ul class="Alert_Icon">
                <li><img src="Landing page/Alerts_icon.png"></li>
                <li id="lefty">Alerts</li>
            </ul>
             <div id="Announcement">
            <ul id="slider"></ul></div>
            <br/><hr/>
        <div id="OPL">
            <ul class="Alert_Icon">
                <li><img src="Landing page/Trainings-OPL_icon.png"></li>
                <li id="lefty">Training & OPLs</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="Links">
            <p style="margin: 0px; font-size: 22pt; padding: 25px 0px 35px 25px; color: #1c3563">Quick Links</p>
            <ul class="bull">
                <li id="bullet"><a href="http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/45641/yash-saraiya">Stackexchange</a></li><hr id="bullety"/>
                <li id="bullet"><a href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/">MSDN</a></li><hr id="bullety"/>
                <li id="bullet"><a href="https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=XikKVrDpMaLv8wfLnYH4BQ">Google</a></li><hr id="bullety"/>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the main tag has a width of 66% whereas the sidebar has a width of 33%. Currently we are actually working on div id="AT" which takes around 25% of total width. Find below the partial snap of the page

[image]

Find below the CSS for the page:

```
.container {
background-color: #bad3df;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;
font-family: "Arial";
}

#content {    
font-size: 14pt;
left: 0%;
position: relative;
height: 75%;
width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
width: 28%;
height: 99%;
float: right;
}

#water {
position: absolute;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.main {
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 2px;
width: 70%;
height:99%;
}

#chart{
position: relative; 
margin-left: 14%;
}

#rect{
position: relative;
height: 35px;
border: px solid transparent;
background-color: #5ca3ca;
margin-left: 85px;
font-size: 22pt;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

article {
text-align: justify;   
margin-left: 85px;
}

p.text{
padding-top: 40px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}

#contact{
position: relative;
margin-top: 60px;
}

.contact-img {
padding: 40px 0px 15px 0px;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
border: none;
display: flex;
padding-left: 0px;
}

.Alert_Icon {
position: relative;
list-style: none;
border: none;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 25px;
display: flex;
padding: 20px 10px 25px 0px;
color: #357ebc;
}

ul {
margin-left: 1.1rem;
}

.QL_Icon {
position: relative;
list-style: none;
border: none;
margin-bottom: 0px;
display: flex;
padding-left: 0px;
}

.contact-img li {
display: table-cell;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
vertical-align: middle;
/* margin-left: 25px; */
width: 69px;
height: 72px;
flex: 1;
}

.Alert_Icon li {
display: table-cell;
padding: 20px 10px 25px 0px;
font-size: 20pt;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.QL_Icon li {
display: table-cell;
padding: 0px 20px 12px 25px;
font-size: 20pt;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.contact-img td{
border: 1px solid red;
}

hr {
display: block;
height: 1px;
border: 0;
border-top: 1px solid #82adcc;
margin: 0em 0;
padding: 0;
}

#cr {
padding-top: 40px;
margin-left: 85px;
}

#AT{
margin-left: 50px;
margin-right: 40px;
height: 60%;
margin-bottom: 20px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#Links{
margin-left: 50px;
margin-right: 40px;
height: 36%;
background-color: #d8e6ed;
}

#align{
vertical-align: middle;
}

#Announcement {
position: relative;
height: 100px;
width: 190px;
/* height: 30%; */
overflow: auto;
font-size: 14pt;
text-decoration: underline;
margin-left: 25px;
margin-right: 40px;
list-style-type: none;
}

#lefty{
position: relative;
top: 10px;
display: table-cell;
padding: 20px 10px 25px 0px;
font-size: 20pt;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
}

#bullet {
padding: 0px 0px 12px 0px;
margin-left: 25px;
list-style-image: url('Landing page/Bullet.png');
/* position: relative; */
left: 25px;
right: 40px;
}

.bull{
/* padding-left: 25px; */
margin-left: 25px;
margin-right: 40px;
}

#bullety {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 12px 0px;
/* padding-bottom: 12px; */
border: solid #bac6cc;
border-width: 1px 0 0;
clear: both;
height: 0;
/* margin: 1.25rem 0 1.1875rem; */

}

#slider{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 2px;
margin: 0px;
}

p#Contact_Name_Align {
display: table-cell !important;
vertical-align: middle !important;
height: 72px !important;
}

#slide{
padding: 4px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#headalign{
position: relative;
top: 40px;
margin: 0px 0px 40px 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

a {
color: #357ebc !important;
line-height: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
}

#AlertImg{
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
list-style-type:none;
line-height:50px;
}

#AlertImg:before{
content:'';
display:inline-block;
width:50px;
height:50px;
background:url('Landing page/Alerts_icon.png');
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
}

#TOPL{
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
list-style-type:none;
line-height:50px;
}

#TOPL:before{
content:'';
display:inline-block;
width:50px;
height:50px;
background:url('https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/09/29/Trainings-OPL_icon.png');
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
}
```

**NOTE:** You may find a lot of redundant CSS since this is the first time I am creating a page from the scratch.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the CSS pseudo class `:before` to add your own image to the list :

```
#bullet:before{
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:url('https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/09/29/Alerts_icon.png');
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

So you can play with `line-height:50px;`to vertically position your text:

```
#bullet{
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style-type:none;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

[Exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/h1oe5pun/)

---

EDIT:

As it is now, it doesn't seem it has to be dynamic, so you can add a special class for long text (and in particular in your case where you should add a 
 before "&" for a better render):

```
.bullet{
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style-type:none;
    line-height:50px;
    width:150px;
    margin:15px 0;
}
.twoLine{
    line-height:25px;
}
.bullet:before{
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:url('https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/09/29/Alerts_icon.png');
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

[Exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/zybao0ey/)

NB: According to me, if it must be responsive, it cannot be done with `line-height`. Maybe a mix `line-height` & Javascript

Comment: Can you please check my edited question. I realized that still one problem exists.

Comment: I am actually creating a custom page and embedding it on SharePoint.. The entire code is quite lengthy... Do you need CSS also with the HTML?

Comment: Ideally image should be responsive, but as of now I am giving up on it and looking for a basic structure

Comment: I have included the HTML, CSS and a snapshot for your reference

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to keep text in `span` and than make it align to the middle.

Check this snippet may it can help you..

```css
#bullet {

  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;

  list-style-image: url('https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/09/29/Alerts_icon.png');

}

span {

  position: absolute;

  top: 32px;

}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li id="bullet">
      <span>Alerts</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inner span, set that span to `position: relative` and `top: -20px`. This will place your text 20px higher where it would normally be. A working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/1acfLqwr/1/

Comment: Will this show the same effect in all resolutions? I guess no... since this is not the responsive way of positioning your text in a list. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You're correct, the answer of EdenSource might fit you better.

Answer (score 0):

vertical center align is the most horrible thing in css.
You could do it easily in javascript, but you asked only for css or css3.
If the size of your containers is fixed and is not related to anything, you can try with `padding` or `margin` `top` and `bottom` to adjust.
If not, javascript will save your life.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  size = document.getElementById('idofyourcontainer');
  size = size.height;
  elementSize = document.getElementById('theElementYouWantToReplace');
  elementSize.style.marginTop = (size - elementSize.height) / 2;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//HTML
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li id="bullet1">Alerts</li>
        <li id="bullet2">Alerts</li>
        <li id="bullet3">Alerts</li>
    </ul>
</div>

//CSS
 #wrapper { position: relative; }
 ul { padding-left: 50px; }
 ul > li { line-height: 50px; }
 li[id^='bullet']:before {
    content: url(https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/09/29/Alerts_icon.png);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
 }
```

`:before` and `line-height` is the way to go, here is [a small jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/9mmyou8s/). ul padding must equal image width, and li line-height must equal image height. Thats all. :)

Comment: Will this show the same effect for different resolutions? I am looking for a responsive design solution. Thanks

Comment: If you have a long text, try to add `ul > li { word-wrap: break-word; }`. Other than that, if you want your image size to be dynamic, this solution wont work. Do you plan to have the image resize based on screen resolution? With the word-wrap CSS it should work on all screen-widths, and adjust accordingly(unless the screen is less than 50px).

Comment: Yes, I would like my image to be resized for different resolution. What I also observed with your code is that it is not eliminating the standard bullet, instead it is just placing the image on that standard bullet. I just changed the value of left attribute to 50px and saw a standard bullet below that image.

Comment: Whoopsy, easy fix on the standard list bullets: `ul > li { list-style-type: none; }` :) [updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/7hhudy72/)

Comment: In a list like this, I would highly recommend have a static font-size, and therefore also line-height. And therefore also a static size on the bullet image to avoid it getting stretched when height is static but width is not.